# Can we delete approval history records?

Tags: approval-process

We have hit the limit for approval processes. There are inactive ones which can be deleted but we can't delete it without deleting the associated records. Is there a way to delete only the approval history records?

Comment: What problem are you running into while attempting to delete approval history records? Can you elaborate more on what you have tried so far?

Comment: @arut when deleting an approval process, it's associated records must be deleted also. we're trying to find a workaround for this by deleting the approval history records. I've only tried it with querying the records in the dev console and deleting from there but it came back with insufficient privilege error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot delete approval history records.  Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdYgHUAV/delete-approval-history).

Also, you can only delete an inactive approval process that has no data records associated with it.

Comment: do you know if support can help delete these for us?

Comment: No, support will not be able to delete even if you log a case.